# FormsAuthentication Roles without Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I'm trying to use FormsAuthentication and it's working fine at the moment with user name and password. I need to add User Role to the Forms authentication Ticket and i'm not using ASP.NET Membership.

```
if (rep.CheckUser(model.UserName, model.Password,out UserRole))//Check User
  {

  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

 // Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, UserRole);//This Requires Membership

  return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);

 }
```

Comment: Which mechanism are you using now for working with Roles?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic At my database table i have UserName,Password and Role for a User.I want to pass the Role retrieved from database table to the Authentication ticket

Comment: Not sure it works that way. You only put the username in the auth cookie and then for each incoming request you read the username from auth cookie and load other details from database. That can be done in an `ActionFilter`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`FormsAuthenticationTicket` constructor (the one with the most parameters) has `userData` parameter which takes a string. It is here that you can add your roles, separated by some character like pipe (|) or hash. How you plan to use is up to you. What you would normally do is to register `AuthenticateRequest` event. So, you could create a ticket this was:

```
private void CreateTicket()
{
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            version: 1,
            name: UserName,
            issueDate: DateTime.Now,
            expiration: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(httpContext.Session.Timeout),
            isPersistent: false,
            userData: String.Join("|", arrayOfRoles));

    var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

    httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

After that in `global.asax` you would do something like this:

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.AuthenticateRequest += OnAuthenticateRequest;
}

private void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var decodedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        var roles = decodedTicket.UserData.Split(new[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, roles);
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
}
```

Now you have roles in IPrincipal object (`HttpContext.Current.User`) and when you query with `HttpContext.Current.User.IsUserInRole("RoleName")` you will get true or false. That way you should be able to avoid using `Roles` provider.

UPDATE: A better event to call in order to handle recreating User principal is `Application_AuthenticateRequest` instead of `BeginRequest`. I have updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: Good answer, although this throws null reference exception if user is not authenticated. Use `base.PostAuthenticateRequest += OnAfterAuthenticateRequest;` instead

Comment: Good answer. But if you are using standard FormsAuthorization then you don't need to decrypt ticket again... you can simply say `var decodedTicket = ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket;`

Comment: I haven't tried this mostly because I've been encrypting the ticket. However, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer, but I would like to mention that the `HttpContext.Session.Timeout` time is stored in minutes (default is `20`), so you should use `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(HttpContext.Session.Timeout)` rather than `AddSeconds(...)`