# How do I prevent unauthenticated access to .csv file in sub folder using forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application that uses forms authentication and allows users to have some non-ASP.NET files like .txt or .csv created in a subfolder for download. While access to the subfolder for browsing is correctly blocked if the user is not signed in, viewing/downloading .txt or .csv files is possible without being signed in. How do I ensure that only logged in user are able to download any files from that subfolder (without additional login)?

My last try was this (found in some other posting) in web.config, to try to force ASP.NET to also handle .csv and .txt files and include them in its forms authentication:

```
<system.webServer> 
  <modules> 
    <remove name="UrlAuthorization" /> 
    <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" /> 
  </modules>
...
```

Comment: you can do it via web.config. Examples are available if you google it. P.S.  just a pedant's note: "authentification" is not a word. "Authentication" is, though.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that (googling, and reading blog posts and similar questions here), and tried various combinations of web.config changes in the main folder, another web.config in the sub folder, fiddling with the UrlAuthorization module, but failed miserably.
Spelling error fixed, thanks!

Comment: In that case please show what you tried (your best/closest attempt) and explain the results, maybe it's nearly right and we can fix it simply.

Comment: I did not get close / halfway there or something like that, just attempts where the file is always accessible or never :-) My last try was this (found in some other posting) in web.config, to try to force ASP.NET to also handle .csv and .txt files and include them in its forms authentication:

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
       <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
       <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"  />
   </modules>

Comment: please add extra info to the question using the "edit" feature. Code in comments is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in the main web.config finally did it for me, without the need for any other changes. It forces all file types to be processed by ASP.NET, including CSV files, so all files are now protected by forms authentication. I just hope though that this does not have any unwanted side effects, as this solution is more global than what I hoped for, not just to protect one specific file type in one subfolder. Comments welcome.

```
<system.webServer> 
 <modules> 
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />    
  <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />    
  <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />    
  <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />    
  <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />    
  <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />    
 </modules> 
</system.webServer>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, this should do the trick:

```
<location path="Folder/">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="YOURROLE" />
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

In order for this to work I think application must be running in integrated mode or at least introduce the file types in mime settings.

Comment: absolutely right. This should be done using config file

Comment: Thanks, but what if I am not using roles? I am using forms authentication where I just check the user name and password against my own table, without any roles. Is there a default role that is used then? I tried setting one via "HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, new[] {"user"});" and used that "user" role in web.config, but this resulted in my background bitmaps etc., which are in a Bitmaps\ subfolder, not loading anymore due to access restrictions.

Comment: So where are you storing the login info ? Session variable, cookie/ ticket ?

Comment: I would suggest on using the FormsAuthenticationTicket. Its pretty easy, you can check the basic principle from an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934752/9187960)

Comment: I am not storing it myself anywhere, just calling FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false) after successful login. Later on I can always get the user name from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

I will check out the other question, thanks!

Comment: Sorted out the bitmap problem, it was because I still had the UrlAuthorization stuff in the web.config, sorry.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted